# Rails + Memcache: Do I need to install memcache on my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to setup memcache on my rails project with this configuration:

`config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, 'localhost', { :namespace => 'preview' }`

I looked through the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore but there's only one short paragraph on it. Is the configuration line enough to make memcache work? I thought I would have to install something on my server, but can't find any documentation/tutorials on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Memcached. If you have Mac, I highly recommend homebrew (http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install memcached
```

Comment: Thanks Omar. So do I have to configure memcached after that to fit my Rails configuration?

Comment: It will use the default configurations, so no need to change anything else. You will only need to run the memcached server.

Comment: I would also recommend if you can to use dalli (https://github.com/mperham/dalli)